# Using plain sql in slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I'm trying to figure out how to use plain sql in slick (postgres). Most examples just have something like:

`db.run(sqlu"""INSERT...."""")`

But `sqlu`, `tsql`, and all other variations give a 'can't find symbol', even though I'm importing

`import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._`

What do I need to import in order to have `sqlu`, `tsql`, etc resolve and not return a 'can't find symbol'?

Using slick 3.3.2.

Comment: ```
Plain SQL queries in Slick are built via string interpolation using the sql, sqlu and tsql interpolators. They are available through the standard api._ import from a Slick profile
```
From slick documentation
http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.2/sql.html#string-interpolation

Comment: @ShankarShastri But I AM importing a slick profile, `import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._`, but these functions are not being imported for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share GitHub repo, if open source?

Comment: @ShankarShastri It isn't open source unfortunately, do you happen to have an example where pulling in `sqlu` through postgres profile is working? Here's my build.sbt: https://gist.github.com/aliakhtar/308429f9bc323547717cb0246f92fd08